# Spacing between image and text in the button

Tags: android, button

I want to create a button as it is in the first picture. But my output is like in the second picture. How can i achieve the correct spacing between image and text in the button and also the shadow as it is in the first picture. How can i achieve this.

My code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:left="2dp" android:top="4dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#1E90FF" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <!-- SHADOW LAYER -->
        <item android:left="4dp" android:top="4dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#C0C0C0" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <!-- CONTENT LAYER -->
        <item android:bottom="5dp" android:right="4dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#DADADA" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Sorry i am not able to post the images

Comment: Share the image url in comment or in the question, we will update in the question.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yH73L.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0CAH.png

Comment: why are you use it totaley on button draw text and image you can take linearLayout and then designe image button etc

Comment: just give 5dp padding on main layout

Answer (score 0):

try with this code this is running code you can use this code ..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lla"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" 
    > 
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="FIND PRODUCTS"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: look at this image ui]

Comment: there you can give space for text as well as button no need to make it complex for small thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><layer-list>
            <item android:left="2dp" android:top="4dp"><shape>
                    <solid android:color="#1E90FF" />
                </shape></item>
        </layer-list></item>
    <item><layer-list>

            <!-- SHADOW LAYER -->
            <item android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp"><shape>
                    <solid android:color="#C0C0C0" />
                </shape></item>
            <!-- CONTENT LAYER -->
            <item android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp"><shape>
                    <solid android:color="#DADADA" />
                </shape></item>
        </layer-list></item>


</selector>
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconLeft"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconLeft"
        android:text="Find Product"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconRight"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photos" />
</RelativeLayout>
```